# can we store aggregate mediator result payload into a property mediator in wso2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have list of customer Accounts, by using iterate mediator iterating over customer ID, with this ID calling one HTTP endpoint through call mediator finally using aggregate mediator Iam combining all the result payload and I want to store the result payload in property mediator for further use case.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your result payload is JSON, you can use a json-path expression to store the response body to a property in the `onComplete` section of the Aggregate Mediator as follows,

```xml
<onComplete xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
    <!-- Store the result payload in the response_body property -->
    <property name="response_body" expression="json-eval($)"></property>
    <log level="custom" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <property name="text"
                expression="$ctx:response_body"/>
    </log>
    <!-- List of mediators or sequnce reference -->
</onComplete>
```

If you are getting a SOAP response, it's better to use the `$body`. Refer https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/property-reference/accessing-properties-with-xpath/#body

Answer (score 1):

As Sanoj mentioned, aggregated message converges in the `onComplete` block when the complete condition is met. So you can use any mediator as usual here. other than the Property Mediator, you can also use the `Enrich Mediator` within the complete block.

```xml
<enrich>
    <source type="body"/>
    <target type="property" property="payload"/>
</enrich>
```